# R vectorization of a function

Tags: r

I need a good vectorization on b of this function:

```
match(TRUE, b <= a)
```

For example:

```
 # EDIT
 a <- c(2,3,5,6,7,8,10,12) #edited
 b <- c(1,3,11)
 #output should be: 1 2 8
 findInterval(b,a) + 1 # 1 3 8
 findInterval(b,a) + 1 - ifelse(!is.na(match(b,a)),1,0) # 1 2 8
```

*EDIT:*

> `findInterval(b,a) + 1` is a partial answer, it works only if the
>   test is `b < a`. But i need `b <= a`. My guess is :
>   `findInterval(b,a) +1 - ifelse(!is.na(match(b,a)),1,0)`, but i would like a better version
>   of `ifelse(!is.na(match(b,a)),1,0)` or a better answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `cut`/`findInterval` :

```
findInterval(b, a) + 1
#[1] 1 2 8
```

Using `cut` :

```
cut(b, c(-Inf, a), labels = FALSE)
#[1] 1 2 8
```

---

If we also want to match on borders we can use `left.open = TRUE`.

```
findInterval(b,a, left.open = TRUE) + 1
#[1] 1 2 8
```

Comment: In general, your first solution doesn't work. I tried this:`b1 <- array(-1, dim = 10)`
     `b2 <- array(-1, dim = 10)`
       `a <- sort(sample(1:200, 100))`
      `b <- sample(1:200, 10)`
        `for(i in seq(1, length(b))){`
         `b1[i] <- match(TRUE, b[i] <= a)`
       `}`
        `b2 <- findInterval(b,a) + 1` b1 is different from b2

Comment: it works only when the test is `b < a`

Comment: `findInterval(b,a) + 1 -ifelse(!is.na(match(b,a)),1,0)`

Comment: @vrige Can you update your post with the example. It is difficult to copy/paste your example from comments.

Comment: @vrige See updated answer. We need to include `left.open = TRUE`.

Comment: @vrige Also I see that `cut` already gives you the expected output.